# Sickle cell life span

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, pathology, hematology, red-blood-cell

How long do sickle red blood cells "live" before being broken down in phagocytosis?

I had trouble doing a normal search as it brings up life span of those inflicted with the disease. Also, I have been doing a semester long assignment, where we are delving into all aspects of this disease, and I have 20 sources so far and still haven't come across the answer.

Comment: Try changing the order of the words. :) [lifespan of rbcs in sickle cell anemia](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&channel=iphone_bm&source=hp&ei=oBt9WujuHI7VzgLBxYfgBg&q=lifespan+of+rbcs+in+sickle+cell+anemia&oq=lifespan+of+rbcs+in+sickle+cell+anemia&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.241.16027.0.16546.39.36.0.2.2.0.247.3966.11j23j1.35.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.37.4002.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i20i264k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1j0i131i20i264k1j33i21k1.0.6qClZILIH3Q)

Comment: A better title would be "Lifespan of sickle cells" (fewer words and no abbreviations). I'd change it myself, but am voting to close as there is no indication of which of the many sources on sickle cell anaemia the poster was unable to find the information in.

Comment: Hi Brittt,. welcome to Bio.SE. Please share a few of the sources you've already read to indicate to the community that you've done your own prior research. This will likely stave off a full close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Sickle cells usually die after about 10 to 20 days, compared to normal red blood cells, which live an average of 120 days. The bone marrow can't make new red blood cells fast enough to replace all the dying ones which causes anemia,low blood count that results in fatigue,shortness of breath and related symptoms.As the cells are made normally but die too rapidly,this is termed as haemolytic.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! Although this could potentially answer the question we prefer to have answers backed up by references. Un-referenced answers may be challenged or flagged for deletion.